# Elixir utility function to return sublist from List based on index and size

Tags: elixir

Is there any utility function in Elixir from which I want to get sublist from array based on index and size?

Enum utility doesn't provide this functionality

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
from=2
size=3
res = sublist(arr,from,size)
#res should return [3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Enum.slice/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#slice/3) like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] |> Enum.slice(2, 3)
[3, 4, 5]
```

Or without the pipe operator like this:

```
Enum.slice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 2, 3)
[3, 4, 5]
```